# How to navigate just one page back on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

guy. I am struggling with navigation in my phone app. I have added three blank pages to my project and managed to navigate forward for page to page but ....
I want a user when click the "back button" on the phone go back just one page and of course when he press it again go back to the main page. What happens is, that at the moment user exits the app when pressing the back button on the device.
This is the code I have got by default in method called:

```
    private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.GoBackCommand.CanExecute(null))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        this.GoBackCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

This is what I have tried to put in the method instead, and what I found on internet but didn't work:

```
if (Frame.CanGoBack)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    Frame.GoBack();
}
```

and this one (quite similar) but didn't work either Frown | :(

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    rootFrame.GoBack();
}
```

I finally tried to build the new app using basic pages instead of blank ones then pasting code but it field again. Please Help Me. I'v giving up.

Here is my code behind for second page

```
// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=390556

namespace NutriPal
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class ListPage : Page
    {

        public ListPage()
        {

            this.InitializeComponent();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

            BrowsingManager browsing = (BrowsingManager) e.Parameter as BrowsingManager;
            if (browsing != null)
            {
                listOfItems.DataContext = browsing;
                //pageTitle.Text = browsing.Title;
            }

        }
```

Chunk of code that may help NavigationHelper

```
  public class NavigationHelper : DependencyObject
    {
        private Page Page { get; set; }
        private Frame Frame { get { return this.Page.Frame; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="NavigationHelper"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="page">A reference to the current page used for navigation.  
        /// This reference allows for frame manipulation and to ensure that keyboard 
        /// navigation requests only occur when the page is occupying the entire window.</param>
        public NavigationHelper(Page page)
        {

            this.Page = page;


            // When this page is part of the visual tree make two changes:
            // 1) Map application view state to visual state for the page
            // 2) Handle hardware navigation requests
            this.Page.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
            {
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
                Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
#else
                // Keyboard and mouse navigation only apply when occupying the entire window
                if (this.Page.ActualHeight == Window.Current.Bounds.Height &&
                    this.Page.ActualWidth == Window.Current.Bounds.Width)
                {
                    // Listen to the window directly so focus isn't required
                    Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated +=
                        CoreDispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated;
                    Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed +=
                        this.CoreWindow_PointerPressed;
                }
#endif
            };

            // Undo the same changes when the page is no longer visible
            this.Page.Unloaded += (sender, e) =>
            {
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
                Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
#else
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated -=
                    CoreDispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated;
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed -=
                    this.CoreWindow_PointerPressed;
#endif
            };
        }

 public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            var frameState = SuspensionManager.SessionStateForFrame(this.Frame);
            this._pageKey = "Page-" + this.Frame.BackStackDepth;

            if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)
            {
                // Clear existing state for forward navigation when adding a new page to the
                // navigation stack
                var nextPageKey = this._pageKey;
                int nextPageIndex = this.Frame.BackStackDepth;
                while (frameState.Remove(nextPageKey))
                {
                    nextPageIndex++;
                    nextPageKey = "Page-" + nextPageIndex;
                }

                // Pass the navigation parameter to the new page
                if (this.LoadState != null)
                {
                    this.LoadState(this, new LoadStateEventArgs(e.Parameter, null));
                }
            }
```

Comment: The app exits from second page or the main page? Can you check how many times you subscribe to *HardwareButtons_BackPressed*? (check also in app.xaml.cs). Check also if you use NavigationHelper.

Comment: I have MainPage that my app use to start with, second and third page. I have Common folder and NavigationHelper inside. As far as I can tell there is one subscription:      Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;

Comment: Can you check if your Pages use NavigationHelper (there should be `this.NavigationHelper = new NavigationHelper;`)? If so then navigation helper subscribes to back button. Check if you have second subscription in app.xaml.cs, if so, then there may be a chance that your code fires two event handlers responsible for back navigation.

Comment: I paste code so You can have a look. Tell me what chunk of code You need to know where I am, cause I'm confused. Where should I look for this.NavigationHelper=new NavigationHelper;

Comment: This seems to be a blank age which is not using NavigationHelper (in comparison to Basic page template). Where do you subscribe to BackButton? Is it possible that you can share the sample project? Side note: NavigationHelper is a template, so if you hadn't changed it, then there is no need to paste it here.

Comment: THHHHANNKK YOU! You've just fixed my app! Thanks to You just started compering code behind from basic page and found it: ) As You said, the pages didn't subscribed  to this. I just pasted what was missing and done:)  Thanks a lot !!!! It's my first app, so I'm struggling with everything :) O z polski:)

Comment: Then good luck with your first app :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("PageName", UriKind.Relative));
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

    }
```